# How can I generate new object names when adding to a list

Tags: c#, list, object

I am adding an option in which new people can be added, who in turn are being entered into a list. This is the relevant snippet:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter the persons name");
string _name = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Enter the persons height");
string heightinput = Console.ReadLine();                    
decimal _height = Convert.ToDecimal(heightinput);
                    
Person personnum = new Person(_name, _height);
_userlist.AddPerson(personnum);
```

How can I make it so the object name is automatically generated (i.e where personnum is)?

Comment: You should elaborate on your question. Why do you want it and what results do you expect to get from the question?

Comment: This question is likely extremely simple to solve (and possibly solved in the answers), however the question is unclear. Please read [ask]

Comment: Note that `personnum` is the name of a *variable* - not an *object*. Variable names need to be known at compile time, but *objects* don't have names as such. We definitely need to know more before we can help confidently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess wat you need is either a default value for auto properties like following:

```
public string Name { get; set;} = "Default Value"
```

Another option is to define a list with possible values and then retrieve a random value that you assign like following

```
Random random = new Random();
string[] array = { "Hallo", "OtherValue" };
int randomNumber = random.Next(0, array.Length);
string variableToAssign = array[randomNumber];
```

I hope this is an approach for you please comment if you need further help!

Answer (score 1):

You can generate random name at every new instance of your object in constructor :

```
public Person(string _name, double _height)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_name)) this._name = GetRandomName();
    }
```